# Download image which is src attribute (base64)

Tags: ajax, image, base64

through AJAX I receive a image in base64 which I adjunct to the src attribute of a img tag.

I want to offer an option to download that image, is it possible to take the data of the src attribute and download it? This is because I cannot download the image again from the server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `window.location` to the encoded URI (or open a popup window), eg

```
window.location.href = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo....
```

Comment: Is there anyway to specify filename?

Comment: Also this just displays the image in memory, it doesn't actually download the file.